# Split cloud function in helper function and async await

Tags: typescript, firebase, asynchronous, google-cloud-functions

I have a http triggered Google cloud function that returns some stats for a given user.
Since other cloud functions should use the stats fetching from the firestore database as well, I want to split it into a helper function. It looks like this:

```
async function getStatsForUser(userId: string) {
    console.log(userId); // printed properly
    const stats = {};

    const docs = await admin.firestore().collection('stats')
        .where('user', '==', userId)
        .orderBy('key', 'desc').limit(1).get();

    docs.forEach(doc => {
        stats["key"] = doc.data().value;
        console.log("stats", stats); // this is never printed
        return stats;
    });
}
```

And the http cloud function (basically just for testing at the moment) like this:

```
export const getStats = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {

    const userId = request.query.userId;

    try {
        const stats = await getStatsForUser(userId);
        console.log("stats2", stats); // printed but empty
        response.send(stats); // nothing is received on client site

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        response.status(500).send(error);
    }
});
```

So the log output looks like this:

```
userId abcdef...
stats2
```

So somehow the cloud function is returning before awaiting the async helper. 
I know I have some problems with the async/await's but I cant get it to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You assign the `stats` variable to the return value of `getStatsForUser`, but the `getStatsForUser` function doesn't return anything.

Comment: You should also log the value of `docs` - I suspect your query is returning an empty array, which is why `forEach`'s log never executes.

Comment: Also, `.forEach(() => { return; })` doesn't return from the enclosing function, but from the particular iteration of the `forEach`.

Comment: @Sean Vieira: You're right, somehow the where() leaded the query to not return anything. Without it I get the log output for the stats, but stats2 is still empty.

Comment: @Sean Vieira: Returning in the forEach is ugly I know, but I couldn't find a better solution to just return the first document (since I limit(1) there is only one).

Comment: My point is that `const hmm = () => [1, 2, 3].forEach(x => { return x; })` doesn't return `1` when you call `hmm()` - it returns `undefined`, because that's what `forEach` returns.  JavaScript does not have non-local returns.  The `return` is scoped to the `callback` and does not escape it.  If you want the first document just return `docs[0]`.

Comment: Thank you, Sean! You're right. Returning in the forEach does not make sense. It's working now.
Anyhow returning docs[0] does not work since it is a Firebase QuerySnapshot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your foreach loop doesn't print anything, that means your `docs` results contains no matched documents.

`stats` from your stats2 log state is always going to be undefined because `getStatsForUser` never returns anything.  A return inside your foreach loop isn't going to return that value from the function.  It's just returning a value from the function that you passed to foreach, which does not get propagated outside the `getStatsForUser`.  That function `getStatsForUser` needs to have a top-level return statement with the value you want to return.  Try accumulating results during the foreach loop into some variable defined at the top level, then return that variable.

Comment: Simple as that!
I thought I could return from the forEach because I only need the first result (limit(1)..) anyhow. But it makes sense that it just returns from the function passed to forEach.
Thanks, Doug! It's working now.